# linux kernel: why swapper_pg_dir is loaded into cr3 twice

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I'm reading linux 2.6.26 source code.

During kernel startup, the swapper_pg_dir is loaded into cr3 twice.

First time, in arch/x86/kernel/head_32.S, to start paging

```
331     movl $pa(swapper_pg_dir),%eax
332     movl %eax,%cr3      /* set the page table pointer.. */
```

And later, in arch/x86/mm/init_32.c

```
519 void __init paging_init(void)
520 {
521 #ifdef CONFIG_X86_PAE
522     set_nx();
523     if (nx_enabled)
524         printk(KERN_INFO "NX (Execute Disable) protection: active\n");
525 #endif
526     pagetable_init();
527 
528     load_cr3(swapper_pg_dir);                                                                                                                                                                
529 
530     __flush_tlb_all();
531 
532     kmap_init();
533 }
```

Is the 528 line load_cr3(swapper_pg_dir) necessary, since swapper_pg_dir is already loaded into cr3 in head_32.S ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment in arch/x86/mm/init_32.c +376 answers:

```
364 /*                                                                                                                                                                                           
365  * Build a proper pagetable for the kernel mappings.  Up until this
366  * point, we've been running on some set of pagetables constructed by
367  * the boot process.
368  *
369  * If we're booting on native hardware, this will be a pagetable
370  * constructed in arch/x86/kernel/head_32.S.  The root of the
371  * pagetable will be swapper_pg_dir.
372  *
373  * If we're booting paravirtualized under a hypervisor, then there are
374  * more options: we may already be running PAE, and the pagetable may
375  * or may not be based in swapper_pg_dir.  In any case,
376  * paravirt_pagetable_setup_start() will set up swapper_pg_dir
377  * appropriately for the rest of the initialization to work.
378  *
379  * In general, pagetable_init() assumes that the pagetable may already
380  * be partially populated, and so it avoids stomping on any existing
381  * mappings.
382  */
383 static void __init pagetable_init(void)
384 {
```